# Discrepancy in array value when calling a variable from different file - python

Tags: python, numpy

I am facing a little problem while calling a variable from a different file. I
have two different files `train_dataset.py` and `test_dataset.py`. I run the
`train_dataset.py` file from my IDE and note the value of the array variable
`array_val` as given below.

```
array([[ 0.08695652,  0.66459627,  0.08695652,  0.07453416,  0.07453416,
        ... 0.15217391]])
```

Now I switch on to `test_dataset.py` and import `import train_dataset` and print
the value of `array_val` by calling `train_dataset.array_val`, I see a very
different output. The output is given below.

```
    array([[  8.11594203e-01,   1.15942029e-01,   4.05797101e-01,
            ... 1.30434783e-01,   5.65217391e-01,   2.02898551e-01]])
```

Please suggest how do I get rid of it and state the reason of the discrepancy.

Please find the code that I have embedded in my `train_dataset.py`

```
no_of_clusters=9
cluster_centroids=[]
k_means=KMeans(n_clusters=no_of_clusters,n_init=14, max_iter=400)

k_means.fit(matrix_for_cluster)

labels=k_means.labels_
array_val=k_means.cluster_centers_
```

i.e `matrix_for_cluster` is a numpy n-dimensional array.

In my `test_dataset.py` all I do is

```
import train_dataset
print train_dataset.array_val
```

Comment: I have updated the code, Please have a look

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to the random initialization of the k-means algorithm

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

As @ali_m explains nicely in the comments, the line `import train_dataset` re-runs the clustering and the cluster centers are not actually saved from the previous time you ran the code. To do that you can serialise the data with

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load

Comment: Ya, But I run it only once. And then from a different shell I just call the variable that holds the array of centroid position. Do you mean when I call the variable the centroids are re-initialized.

Comment: Run it the same way twice. Do you get the same results?

Comment: No, Results are different for different run that I am aware of, but what I am unable to understand is that, when I run the model once and save the centroid points to a variable and call it from a different shell (train_dataset.array_var) it shows different output, but when I run just array_var  or in the same shell it gives the same output.

Comment: Try adding the line `print array_val` after `array_val=k_means.cluster_centers_` in train_dataset.py

Comment: @user2404193 You are not really "saving" the centroids by assigning them to some variable in your script, since the clustering will still be re-run every time you import or reload your `train_dataset` script. To truly "save" the results, you should write them to some external file (e.g. using `np.save`).